# Parent and child relationship is broken when do the sort based on parent name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort the name based on 1st level (sort only applicable root id is null or level ==1). If I search based on name the result set is broken the parent and child relationship.

I have 500 000 records. What is the best way to do this performance wise?

```
ID  PARENT ID   ROOT ID     NAME        level
===============================================
1   NULL        NULL        FIRST       1
2   1           1           SECOND      2
3   2           1           THIRD       3

4   1           1           FORTH       4
5   4           1           FIFTH       5

6   NULL        NULL        SIXTH       1
7   6           6           SEVENTH     2
8   7           6           EIGHTH      2
9   NULL        NULL        NINTH       1
10  NULL        NULL        TENTH       1
11  NULL        NULL        ELEVEN      1
12  11          11          TWELVE      2
13  12          11          THIRTEEN    3
14  13          11          FOURTEEN    4
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT - SORT BY NAME ASC

```
ID  PARENT ID   ROOT ID     NAME        level
===============================================
11  NULL        NULL        ELEVEN      1
12  11          11          TWELVE      2
13  12          11          THIRTEEN    3
14  13          11          FOURTEEN    4
1   NULL        NULL        FIRST       1
2   1           1           SECOND      2
3   2           1           THIRD       3
4   1           1           FORTH       4
5   4           1           FIFTH       5
9   NULL        NULL        NINTH       1
6   NULL        NULL        SIXTH       1
7   6           6           SEVENTH     2
8   7           6           EIGHTH      2
10  NULL        NULL        TENTH       1
```

Comment: Well, sorting by `NAME` does, unsurprisingly, sort by the `NAME` value.  It's not clear how you *want* this to be sorted.  By `PARENT ID`?  `ROOT ID`?  `level`?  A combination of fields?

Comment: This question is not clear at all, and it shows no research effort.   Post your attempt at solving this and what was the result.

Comment: I dont understand what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to get the parent's name, then use the parent's name to `ORDER`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.[PARENT ID], t1.[ROOT ID], t1.NAME, t1.level
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.ID = t1.[ROOT ID] 
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.NAME, t1.NAME),  t1.level
```

If the parent's name is not available, then this is a case of the current row being the parent itself. Hence the row's `NAME` field is used instead so as to sort.

Finally, records that belong to the same parent are sorted by `level`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to sort the results by two keys:

1. first, by the `NAME` column of the root row associated with each row, which may be that row itself, and
2. second, by the `level` column.

You can achieve this by joining the table to itself to make the root-`NAME` association.  For example,

```
select a.*
from
  my_table a
  join my_table b
    on isnull(a.[root id], a.id) = b.id
order by b.name, a.level
```

Notice the `isnull()` -- although you generally want to join based on `b.id = a.[root id]`, you need to avoid excluding the root rows, whose root_id is `NULL`.  With the `isnull()`, you join those rows based on `id` instead (*i.e.* you join them to themselves).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    id,
    parent_id,
    root_id,
    name,
    level
FROM
    Your_Table T1
INNER JOIN Your_Table T2 ON T2.id = T1.root_id
ORDER BY
    T2.name,
    T1.level
```